# Creating complex contour plots

Tags: plotting

I would like to create a contour plot of $e^z-\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}$ that looks like the picture on the left, but can only manage the one on the right. I have tried incrreasing the number of contours, but this doesn't have any effect. Am I missing something fundamental?

[image]
[image]

```
Show[Table[ContourPlot[{Im[E^(x + I y) - ((x + I y) - 1)/(x + I y) + 1] == k, 
Re[E^(x + I y) - ((x + I y) - 1)/(x + I y) + 1] == k}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -20, 20}, 
ContourStyle -> {Directive[{Red}], Directive[{Blue}]}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, Contours -> 20, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {k, -10, 10, 2}]]
```

The plot I am trying to recreate is from [this website](http://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/tr/) ([specific PDF](http://cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/tr/overflow/2013-sep-oct-3.pdf)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main thing you missed was that the picture on the left shows contours of the amplitude and  phase, not the real and imaginary parts.

I couldn't get a good result for both sets of contours in one plot, so here I create the two plots separately and combine them with `Show`:

```
f[z_] := Exp[z] - (z - 1)/(z + 1)

Show[
 ContourPlot[#1[f[x + I y]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -20, 20},
    ContourStyle -> #2, Contours -> #3, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourShading -> None, PlotPoints -> 30] & @@@ 
   {{Abs, Blue, Exp @ Range[-5, 5]},
   {Arg, Red, Range[-Pi, Pi, Pi/5]}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great - that you ! I just tried something different, but you are right, I did miss that - thank you again :)